# 3-stage Differential Ring Oscillator simulation output remains at DC Value

Tags: ltspice, oscillator, simulation

I'm currently simulating a 3-stage differential Ring Oscillator in LTSpice. I have setup one of my differential stages and created a symbol for it to use in the ring oscillator. I have double checked all my pins to make sure they are correct. Also note the pin at the bottom of the Differential Stage symbol is just a pin to check the voltage of the Va net. However when I run my transient simulation, the output of any of the stages of the ring oscillator remain at a constant DC Value. Is this due to LTSpice not being able to generate noise? I attempted to inject a 5mV pulse into both gates of the transistors and it just created a pulse at the beginning of my output waveform and leveled out to DC. Any help would be appreciated!

Single Differential Stage:

[image]

3-stage Ring Oscillator:

[image]

Output Waveform:

[image]

Comment: @jay he has that already, note the polarity of the inputs and outputs.

Comment: you might need to connect the grounds together

Comment: Yeah I've tried flipping the polarities of one of the stages. @jay

Comment: @Jasen, thanks.. my mistake, will remove mine.

Comment: The pins coming out of each differential stage symbol is just a test point for Va, not ground. @Jasen

Comment: The ring osc. you have relies on gate delay. Test if the gates have enough delay, or add delay.

Comment: Replace the feedback with a pair of voltage sources on the first amplifier stage, driven in opposite directions.  A positive-going pulse on the input should result in a larger, negative-going pulse on the output.  If you do a frequency sweep and plot the differential output voltage (out+ - out-), then at the point where you hit 0 degrees phase shift, the amplitude of the gain should be 0dB or greater.  If it's not, then you're not meeting the Barkhausen criterion for an oscillator, and you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a certain amount of stage gain to oscillate (Barkhausen). My guess is you don't have enough. Two simple ways to try to overcome this.

1. Increase input device gms (i.e. larger width).
2. Increase RL.

If you only increase RL, you might not get decent bias level, so work with parameterizing both options (it will be ok here, since ideal current sources, but bias will look weird).

*Notice it oscillates just fine with no external perturbation/stimulus.

[image]

Comment: Increasing the width of the device worked! Thank you so much the help and intuitive explanation. As both you and TimWescott explained I wasn't meeting the Barkhausen criterion, and that made it make much more sense to me in terms of not reaching enough stage gain.