# Simulating a RC Phase-Shift Oscillator in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, oscillator, phase-shift

I'm having some difficulties in simulating this circuit in LTspice. I'm using op amps in the inverting configuration and buffers between each stage but it's simply not working. The simulation runs for several minutes and then the outputs of the stages come out all messy. I made the calculations and it is supposed to generate an sine wave with a frequency of about 90Hz. The Gain of each stage is supposed to be at least 2. Does anyone know to proper simulate this circuit? The capacitors and resistors are 100 nF and 10kOhm, respectively.
[image]

Comment: Here is an LTspice example with a working ring oscillator. It might be useful to build around it. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/594463/3-stage-differential-ring-oscillator-simulation-output-remains-at-dc-value

Comment: maybe try the alternate solver, that can help sometimes.  Is the ground between the supply rails of the amplifiers?

Comment: that circuit  looks like a relaxation oscillator to me.

Comment: I get \$f_{_0}\approx \frac1{2\pi\,R\,C}\$. With your values this is closer to 160 Hz. How do you get 90 Hz?

Comment: If you were to directly cascade the RC sections without buffering, then I'd find something more like \$f_{_0}\approx \frac1{4.2\,R\,C}\$ which would be closer to 76 Hz. But you've got buffering going on, so the successive passive loading effects aren't there. I need to see your theory and resulting quantitative calculations.

Comment: Please show us your actual LTspice schematic.

Comment: I can read that you are using "opamps in inverting configuration" AND "buffers". I can identify only three fixed gain amplifiers with a gain of "at least 2". At least ? What does this mean? Do you know the gain which is required by the oscillation condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

1. Use ideal gain stages with gain of 2 each.
2. Inject small current pulse to force startup. (note I saw jp314 earlier post after I simulated -- mostly same idea).
   [image]

Comment: Or create a small imbalance by adding e.g. `ic=1` to one of the capacitors. It would be nice if OP set the gains to `1` for two of the VCVSs, and to `{x}` for any one of them. Then, adding a voltage source with `AC 1` in the feedback and using `.step param x 6 10 1` with `.ac dec 101 1 1k` will clearly show the condition for oscillation.

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfmB3.png) is yet another approach that works in LTspice.

Answer (score 3):

If the 'K' elements are ideal components (no limitation on output voltage), then the circuit loop will have infinite gain and won't give reasonable results.

Put back-back diodes across each resistor.

Also, SPICE may not start an oscillation after it finds the DC bias point -- you may need to add a small perturbation to some node (e.g. a current source pulse that starts at 1 uA and switches to 0 at 1 us).